# How to Convert 2 Strings To Date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, multiple-columns, concatenation, str-to-date

i have a table tbl_remit.

```
 ________________________________________________________________
|RemitNo|ID|Employer|From_Month|From_Year|To_Month|To_Year|Amount|
|   1   |1 |    a   |   01     |   2016  |   01   |  2016 |200.00|
|   2   |1 |    a   |   02     |   2016  |   02   |  2016 |200.00|
|   3   |1 |    a   |   03     |   2016  |   03   |  2016 |200.00|
|   4   |1 |    a   |   04     |   2016  |   06   |  2016 |600.00|
```

This table represents the remittance of `Employer(a)` with `ID(1)` for the month of `From_Month(01)` `From_Year(2016)` `To_Month(01)` `To_Year(2016)` Amounting to `Amount(200.00)`.

The employer paid 200.00 for the month of January 01, 2016 - January 31, 2016 . I need to create a view which combines the columns FROM_Month and FROM_Year as Date with the Format of 01/01/2016 and also columns TO_Month and TO_Year as Date with the Format of 01/31/2016.

I used `STR_TO_DATE(Concat('From_To','/','1','/','From_Year'), '%m/%d/%Y')` but it returns `NULL`

Any comments and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be storing your date information using a date type (`date`, `timestamp`, etc.).  But besides this, why do you need an actual date here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the `From_To` and `From_Year` columns:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(From_Year, '/', From_Month, '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d') AS From_Date,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(To_Year,   '/', To_Month,   '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d') AS To_Date
FROM yourTable
```

As general advice, you should always store your date information in a single column, using a date type such as `date` or `timestamp`.

**Update:**

If you wanted to get the last day of the `to` date, you can use the `LAST_DAY` function:

```
LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(To_Year, '/', To_Month, '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d'))
```

Comment: Sir, How can i get the last day of the month for the `To_Date`?

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(To_Year,   '/', To_Month,   '/', LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(To_Year,   '/', To_Month,   '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d')), '%Y/%m/%d') AS To_Date`

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(To_Year, '/', To_Month, '/', LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(To_Year, '/', To_Month, '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d'))), '%Y/%m/%d') AS To_Date
FROM tbl_remit` I used this to get the Last day of the month but the result is like this `2016-01-20`.

Comment: Your query makes no sense to me, and this isn't what I recommended doing.  Just wrap the `STR_TO_DATE` term from my query with `LAST_DAY`.

Comment: I know, I was trying my best, but when I saw your query. I felt so stupid. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: @Clorae Not stupid...writing complex SQL queries correctly can be a real torture, especially if you are new to it.  Glad to help you :-)